# Dataflow Batch or Streaming insert to BigQuery clarification

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

Given that there is cost involved with Streaming inserts to `BigQuery`, does using Dataflow to read from a Bounded Collection (or a batch mode) incur cost from the `BigQuery` perspective? And I believe only when reading from Unbounded collection(in streaming mode) and writing to `BigQuery` is considered a Streaming insert to `BigQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, as [specified in the sources](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1078):

> If the input is bounded, then file loads will be used. If the input is
>   unbounded, then streaming inserts will be used.

You can overwrite the default behaviour by using `.setMethod(Write.Method.FILE_LOADS)` or `.setMethod(Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)` on the `BigQueryIO` builder object.